# Issue with Ansible Check and Diff Mode

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I was going thru this post (https://blog.networktocode.com/post/generating-diff-with-ansible/) where its mentioned that we can use check and diff mode together. I am trying to use that for gold config audit (audit pre decided config against what is present on device) for Cisco and Extreme devices. Below is my playbook –

```
# task to audit & heal ntp configuration
- name: Set NTP template
  ios_config:
     src: "{{domain}}_{{ansible_network_os}}_ntp.cfg"
     match: line
  register: ntp_result
```

Below is my template -

```
ntp server 10.19.70.1
```

Ansible highlighting that it is going to change the config. Below is what result I am getting. Surprisingly I am not getting any config diff.

```
"ntp_result": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
        },
        "changed": true,
        "commands": [
            "configure ntp server add x.x.x.x"
        ],
        "failed": false,
        "updates": [
            "configure ntp server add x.x.x.x"
        ],
        "warnings": [
            "unable to perform diff against running-config due to check mode"
        ]
    }
```

Why I am not getting config diff? Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the module: you can only combine `check` with `diff` using the `diff_against` options of `startup` and `intended`, but not `running`.

corresponding Ansible source [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/bef5ebba6e27017e9db8b13c92dfbf1850d908a3/lib/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_config.py#L532-L535):

```
        if module.params['diff_against'] == 'running':
            if module.check_mode:
                module.warn("unable to perform diff against running-config due to check mode")
```